# Bad Request: The CSRF tokens do not match - pgadmin4 on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, apache2, cloudflare, pgadmin

When I log in to pgadmin4 I get a Bad Request notification.

Pgadmin4 is up and running on http://localhost/pgadmin4, but the databases I connected to earlier are no longer listed due to this Bad Request.

I looked for the answer in several stackoverflow articles but couldn't find the solution: pgadmin4 is not running in Docker and no Django on the server, so those related questions are not relevant. I also tried clearing the cookies in my browser but no result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Reading a couple of more comments on questions related to this topic I noticed people were talking about cloudflare cache and nginx as proxy server having something to do with this issue. I put 1 and 1 together and realized in my case cloudflare was set up as a proxy.

Once I disabled this for my site and **set Cloudflare to DNS Only**, the issue was solved.

```
set Cloudflare to DNS Only
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I'm trying to host pgAdmin behind [Cloudflare Access](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/products/zero-trust/access/), so disabling the proxy isn't an option for me :(   ... I'll post an alternative solution here if I can find one...

Answer (score 1):

If you're bumping into this problem because pgAdmin is behind a Cloudflare proxy, it seems this problem can be resolved by changing the caching level to "No Query String" via the Cloudflare dashboard, under Caching > Configuration > Caching level.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/set-caching-levels/

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflared-pgadmin-and-csrf-token/272751/2